# SpringMVC POST method mapping won't load page when the method contains a specific Class

Tags: java, spring

I have an item class and a form:

```
<form:form method="POST" commandName="item" action="/item/add">

@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String itemAdd(@ModelAttribute("item") Item item){
```

Whenever I include item in the function parameters, the page will not load. A GET method works fine. Including any other class in the parameters (or empty) works fine but obviously I need to use item in the function.

Anyone have any ideas why this isn't working?

Comment: What does "will not load" mean? Do you get an error? What's the status code? If you turn Spring logging to DEBUG, what does it say?

Comment: 404 page not found. In the log there is no error at all. I know i haven't typo'd or anything because if I remove item from the parameters or change to GET, it will load a page.

Comment: Can you try passing the argument as @requestbody ....

Comment: @smrutiranjan Same thing happens

Comment: @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String itemAdd(@requestbody Item item){.....} So have u tried like this and not working ? See 404 page not found means its unable to locate this service it might be due to syntax of service only bcz according to u its working fine with GET

Comment: @smrutiranjan Yep I tried exactly that. I think I know what's happening. In the form I am trying to submit one of the fields is sending an object. If i remove that field then it works fine.